# Safeguarding against extra expenditures Natural disasters during travels

Tags: budget, insurance, natural-disasters

Looking at the recent storms in US/Caribbean and Mexico, i am wondering if there are any pre emptive action which we can take to safeguard against such incidents like any insurance policies to cover extra expenditures.

In case of a storm, most likely all flights will get cancelled and you may need to rebook flights at earlier dates at higher prices to escape or one may need last minute accommodation in different cities. All this will increase costs.

Can we safeguard ourself against these extra costs?

Answer (score 4):

You've answered your own question: **Travel Insurance**.

You can read the fine print to make sure it covers reboookings and other incidentals due to weather/natural disaster if that's a specific concern.

Also note that most airlines have become very proactive and flexible in these situations allowing fee free rebooking or cancellation.

If you do find yourself in an imminent situation, such as a Hurricane, don't wait.  As soon as the airline issues a travel alert and allows changes, go.

Finally, a very proactive thing you can do is just not travel to Hurricane/Typhoon zones in season.

Comment: I wouldn't consider your last point very practical. That pretty much excludes the entire Carribean and Gulf coast for late summer and early autumn.

Comment: @Crazymoomin It is entirely practical as both regions are year round destinations.  In fact, peak Hurricane season is one of the least desirable times to visit due to the generally hot an humid conditions.

Comment: For a lot of travellers with children or work commitments it's not practical advice. That's at the tail end of many countries school holidays, they possibly can't go any other time.

Comment: School ends before or just at the beginning of Hurricane Season so there's plenty of time to take the kids to Walt Disney World with little to no risk of a hurricane.  The best way to deal with a problem is to avoid it.

Comment: That depends on your country of origin, we don't all get 3 month summer holidays. Add that plus other obstacles and you can see why a lot of holidaymakers won't have that option.